# Signalr with asp canvas

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm trying to use a canvas created in javascript in asp (for asp.net application) and am trying to create a connection with signalr. I'm very confused with the syntax.

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WB_api.aspx.cs" Inherits="WhiteBoard.WB_api" %>
```

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="500" style="border:1px solid #000000;" onmousemove="draw(event)" onmousedown="isReady(true,event)" onmouseup="isReady(false,event)"></canvas>

<select id="color">
    <option value="black">Black</option>
    <option value="Red">Red</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
    <option value="white">Eraser</option>
</select>
<select id="size">
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    <option value="30">30</option>
    <option value="40">40</option>
</select>

<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub by class name. 
    var drawHub = $.connection.drawHub;

    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    var pos;
    var ready;
    function draw(e) {
        var ink = document.getElementById("color").value;
        var size = document.getElementById("size").value;
        if (pos == undefined)
            pos = getMousePos(e);
        if (ready) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = ink;
            ctx.lineWidth = size;
            ctx.moveTo(pos.mouseX, pos.mouseY);
            pos = getMousePos(e);
            ctx.lineTo(pos.mouseX, pos.mouseY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    }
    function getMousePos(ev) {
        var x = ev.clientX;
        var y = ev.clientY;

        return {
            mouseX: x,
            mouseY: y
        }

    }
    function isReady(r, e) {
        ready = r;
        pos = getMousePos(e);
    }
</script>
```

I've developed the canvas and it is workable without signalr, but the signalr hub doesn't seem to be working.
 And I don't know what to put after this to work:

```
    var drawHub = $.connection.drawHub;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scenario is something like this:

1. User1 and User2 join the `signalr` hub (basically hit the page)
2. If User1 draws something, it "magically" appears on the User2's screen and vice versa

So keeping that in mind, in this example, you'll have to do something like this:

- capture the co-ordinates of the movement and send these values to the `drawHub` through some method.
- On the server side, that method would pass the values to all the clients, may be after a bit of clean up
- all the clients would be listening/handling that method to receive the co-ordinates and draw the lines on the canvas.

Hope this helps.

Comment: okayh thanks alot for the info.. will take note! Have a nice day! :))